# Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm checking whether or not the username and email the user has entered is taken. Everything works fine; if it's already in use it doesn't register the account and informs the user, but if it's not taken the account is made, however, I get the warning message regardless.

This is where the error is coming from, but based off the tutorials I have been using this code should work fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT Username, Email FROM users WHERE Username = $username AND Email = $email";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows = 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change :
if ($result->num_rows = 0)//assignment
to: 
if ($result->num_rows == 0)//condition checking.
```

Comment: Such a simple mistake :p Thanks :)